# How to save the jpg file from base64 data

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have the base 64 data for my images and I want to save them in my local machine as JPG Files.

My base 64 code starts with

```
data:image/jpg;base64,/...
```

I already tried to save it by the following code:

```
 file_put_contents('MyFile.jpg', base64_decode($imgData1));
```

But I cannot open the created image; it says "the file appears to be damaged, corrupt, or is too large". Could you please let me know what I'm missing.

Also if you need any more clarification, please let me know which part you need more clarification.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get rid of the prefex before calling `base64_decode`.

```
<?php
// get rid of everything up to and including the last comma
$imgData1 = substr($imgData1, 1+strrpos($imgData1, ','));
// write the decoded file
file_put_contents('MyFile.jpg', base64_decode($imgData1));
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks not just base64 but PHP stream wrapper data.

```
file_put_contents('MyFile.jpg', file_get_contents('data:image/jpg;base64,/...'));
```

Comment: It says: failed to open stream: Invalid argument

Comment: This should work with recent versions of PHP, but you may need to replace "data:" with "data://".

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `imagecreatefromstring` and `imagejpeg`, here's an example:

```
$imageStr = base64_decode($imgData1);
$image = imagecreatefromstring($imageStr);
imagejpeg($image, $somePath);
```

Comment: Sorry my files are all JPG files

Comment: Like I said, you'll do something similar - use `imagejpeg` instead of `imagepng`.  Anyway, I updated my answer.